# Does Xamarin Forms Google Maps (Custom Renderer based on <Maps>) Not have a POI onclick method?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin.Forms to build into Android and IOS applications.

I'm also using `Xamarin.maps.googlemaps` library that amay077 built based on xamarin.maps - [github](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/README.md)

This library (as well as `xamarin.maps`) only has an `OnMapClicked` event handler. This library happens to just return the latitude and longitude of the clicked position (see below)
Then I just take that latitude and longitude and query for the nearest POI.

I remember when I built google-maps for specifically Android from Android Studio, when I clicked on the google-map and clicked on one of its POIs that shows with the map, I got some information on the clicked POI.

Is there anything like that for xamarin.maps.googlemaps OR xamarin.maps?
I just want to be able to click the POI icon that comes with the map.

Another implementation is to just load up the entire view port of the map with ugly markers... I kind of want to avoid it.

```
(init)
googlemap.MapClicked += Googlemap_MapClicked;
```

---

```
async void Googlemap_MapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e){
/* HERE I WANT TO ACTUALLY GET SOME SORT OF POI INFORMATION THAT WAS CLICKED*/

/* ORIGINAL CODE */
google_results_layout.IsVisible = false;
GooglePlace place = await vm.GetMostLikelyPlace(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude);
if (place == null)
  await DisplayAlert("Place Not Found!", "Place was not found via Google.", "OK");
else
  vm.SetSelectedLocation(place);
}
```

Comment: You can always mod the source code and expose the POI feature(s), i.e. The `OnPoiClickListener` on the Android Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/poi) and do the same for iOS...

Comment: I guess you're right... I was just trying to be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sp1008/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

I dont know if that is public or not, but I forked amay077's git and made poi changes to it. It turns out it was simpler than I expected.

P.S. I only did it for Android and IOS.